# Bukkit events fired multiple times

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I have this possibly faulty snippet of code:

```
@EventHandler
public void onPlayerInteract(PlayerInteractEvent e) {
    if (e.getAction() == Action.RIGHT_CLICK_AIR && e.getItem().getType() == Material.NAME_TAG && e.getHand() == EquipmentSlot.HAND) {
        e.getPlayer().sendMessage("right click?");
    }
}
```

and every time I right-click air with a nametag, the "right click?" message gets sent 5 times to player on each fire.

Removing `e.getHand() == EquipmentSlot.HAND` still repeats 5 times (was originally added because of [this](https://www.spigotmc.org/threads/playerinteractevent-being-called-multiple-times-when-using-minecarts.85661/) discussion/1.9 dual wielding). I also referred to [this](https://bukkit.org/threads/inventoryclickevent-runs-multiple-times-sometimes.297103/), but it didn't make a difference.

Why does this repeat numerous times instead of 1 time when 1 event occurred?

My entire code is [here](https://pastebin.com/VgHctF7E). The server I'm testing this on is 1.12.2 Spigot.

Edit:
The code to pastebin is the only class used in the Java project.

Answer (score 1):

`onPlayerInteract` is called as long as the event is being detected, and not on the first time the event is detected.

I found this out by right-clicking for a "normal" amount of time (~500ms), which printed 5 times.

Then I just kept right-click held down for ~1000ms, and saw that it printed 5 times again, but did that twice. It appeared to instantly print 5, then another 5.

For my last test, I decided to right-click for the smallest amount of time that I could, and sure enough, only 1 print done (I didn't realize this previously that more were printed due to a small chat box size).

I assumed that this would still work the same by only printing the event with small code:

```
@EventHandler(priority=EventPriority.HIGH)
public void onPlayerInteract(PlayerInteractEvent e) 
{
    e.getPlayer().sendMessage(e.getAction().toString());
}
```

Nothing like that happened, and instead everything was printed once, except when a block was right clicked with an empty hand. [Here's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aakoyjp_QRc&feature=youtu.be) the video depicting what I mean with the above code being used (every once a while in the video, chat is cleared). Using the same body above but instead for `eventRightClick(PlayerInteractEvent e)` does the same thing.

Also, not shown in the video, when left-click is held while moving the mouse over several blocks, `eventRightClick` will fire multiple times. Same for right-click, but in pairs (all done with a free hand).

**EDIT**

Holding right-click while targeting a block with an empty hand will continue to fire in pairs, regardless if mouse targets multiple blocks. See [here](https://youtu.be/rXBGp6mAAtw). Note that `eventRightClick` does this:

```
@EventHandler(priority=EventPriority.HIGH)
public void eventRightClick(PlayerInteractEvent e)
{
    e.getPlayer().sendMessage(
        e.getAction().toString() + " " + e.getEventName());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please subscribe to the sub-event - **PlayerInteractEvent.RightClickBlock**,  rather than the parent event, and check if this works:

```
@EventHandler
public void onPlayerInteract(PlayerInteractEvent.RightClickBlock e) {

   if(e.getAction() != Action.RIGHT_CLICK_AIR ){
       return;
   }

   if(e.getItem().getType() != Material.NAME_TAG ){
       return;
   }
   e.getPlayer().sendMessage("right click?");
}
```

Please check for multiple registrations as well.

Comment: Your solution is the exact same as OP posted... and you can check for yourself that he didn't register multiple times by reading the whole question.

Comment: Ok, but point was to try and use PlayerInteractEvent.RightClickBlock  and see if this resolves the issue. Thanks

Comment: I think I misunderstood how `onPlayerInteract` and `eventRightClick` worked. Apparently they are called as long as right click is held down while interacting.